# Check if a value is not in a list in Application Insights Query Language?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics, aiql

Is there a shorter way to check if a property, say `user_id` is not within a given list:

```
customEvents 
| where user_Id != 123
    and user_Id != 234
    and user_Id != 345
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `!in` [operator](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Scalar-operators/in_!in-operators), code like below:

```
customEvents 
| where user_Id !in (123,234,345)
```

Comment: I'm sure I tried that multiple times yesterday, but it seems to be working now.